# Pagination on a Shopify GET order API call

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-api

I'm trying to write a script that fetches Shopify orders and saves them into a Google Sheet.

When paginating through the Shopify order API my script only seems to pull the first 250 orders and isn't displaying any further data.

Any ideas on why it's failing to pull further orders? On logging the data, it seems to not be pulling the next URL correctly.

```
// Import the required modules
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("OrdersTEST");
let newSheet;

// Define the API endpoint and headers
const endpoint = "https://STOREID.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/orders.json?status=any&limit=250&fields=order_number,id,email,created_at,total_price,current_total_price,financial_status,line_items,tax_lines,gateway, shipping_address,shipping_lines,note_attributes&order=created_at asc";
const apiKeyHeader = {"X-Shopify-Access-Token": "ACCESS TOCKEN"};

// Define the delay time to avoid hitting rate limit
const delayTime = 1000; 

function getOrders() {
  // Initial call to API to get first page of orders
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, {headers: apiKeyHeader});
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  // Check if the sheet exists, if not create it
  if (!sheet) {
    newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet("OrdersTEST");
  }else{
    newSheet = sheet;
  }

  // Clear the sheet
  sheet.clear();

// Add column titles
  newSheet.appendRow(["Order ID", "Email", "Created At", "Total Price"]);

  // Write the orders data to the sheet
  var orders = data.orders;
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
    values.push([orders[i].id, orders[i].email, orders[i].created_at, orders[i].total_price]);
  }
  newSheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  
  // Get next page URL
  var link_header = response.getHeaders()["link"];
  Logger.log("link_header: " + link_header);
  
  // Loop through all pages of orders
  while (link_header) {
    // Wait for delay time to avoid hitting rate limit
    Utilities.sleep(delayTime);
    
    // Call API with next page URL
    var next_link = link_header.match(/<(.*)>; rel="next"/)[1];
    Logger.log("next_link: " + next_link);
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(next_link, {headers: apiKeyHeader});
    data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    link_header = response.getHeaders()["link"];
    Logger.log("link_header after call: " + link_header);
    
    // Write the orders data to the sheet
    orders = data.orders;
    values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
      values.push([orders[i].id, orders[i].email, orders[i].created_at, orders[i].total_price]);
    }
    newSheet.getRange(newSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  }
  Logger.log("Orders data written to sheet successfully!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use REST API Endpoint for that. Check GraphQL Reference and particularly look into [Paginating results with GraphQL](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/pagination-graphql). Note it's not going to be one call and you have to keep in mind that there is a bucket with a limit, where each API call has its cost.